# useState not setting correctly inside useEffect with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, socket.io

I have a chat app that is sending the chat message data through socket.io. The state data is not being set inside of my useEffect.

```
  const [receivedMessage, setReceivedMessage] = useState(null);

  // Get the message from socket server
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.on("receive-message", (data) => {
      console.log("get received message", data);
      setReceivedMessage(data); //Issue is this setState
    });

  }, []);

  //Verify receivedMessage state changed
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("updated received message: ", receivedMessage)
  }, [receivedMessage])
```

`

I can see data is being received from the socket. This is the console.log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEz0.png)

The useEffect to verify receivedMessage never executes.

Comment: Generally you would want to cancel the socket subscription in the callback returned from the useEffect callback.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any way for the `receivedMessage` state to ***not*** update given the code and information provided. There isn't enough context here, and I doubt React is broken. Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve] and details about what you are expecting and where/how you are verifying that state ***did not*** actually update somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Update your setReceivedMessage to this:

```js
      setReceivedMessage((data) => (data));
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, and this does not answer the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).